# symfony2: trying to load fixtures using hautelook/alicebundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fixtures

I have installed these bundles:

```
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "dev-master"
```

I have this fixtures:

```
// src/Sermovi/Bundle/ManagementBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/test.yml
Customer:
    user0:
        name: bob
    user1:
        name: alice
```

When I run `doctrine:fixtures:load` I get this:

```
  > purging database
  > loading Sermovi\Bundle\ManagementBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\TestLoader
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Customer' not found in /home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/Loader/Base.php on line 404
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maybe use the FQCN of the Customer class, e.g.

```
Sermovi\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Customer:
    user0:
        name: bob
    user1:
        name: alice
```

Comment: thanks, you gave me the hint, this is working: `Sermovi\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Customer`